They don't like his behaviour which irritate/irritates everyone
Which verb is correct, irritate or irritates and why?

You can figure it out by considering, What’s the subject of the verb to irritate?

We'd normally expect a comma (pause, in speech) before which, which is here being used as a "pronoun" standing in for his behaviour.
Without a comma / pause, the word which would be introducing a restrictive relative clause. A restrictive clause would mean they specifically only dislike that part of his behaviour that irritates people, but the intended sense (i.e. - that all of his behaviour irritates people) is more obvious if we replace  which by a new statement without a pronoun...

They don't like his behaviour. His behaviour irritates everyone.

...where the verb is singular irritates because his behaviour is singular (thus it's still singular when referenced by pronoun which).
